# Android Stopping Foreground Service when device locks

Tags: android

On my Android 12 device, the ActivityManager is stopping my foreground service when the device locks. The service's purpose is to get GPS info and do various tracking and specialty geofencing (which cannot be handled by the regular GeoFencing features). I need it to run all the time.

My Activity does:

```
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, NavService.class); // Build the intent for the Navigation service
            if (!isNavServiceRunning())
            {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                {
                    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "startForegroundService(NavService)");
                    context.startForegroundService(intent);
                } else
                    context.startService(intent);
            }
```

and that Log.v entry does show up.

Then my Service does:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    {
        NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "Foreground Service Channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle(getText(R.string.nav_service_title))
                .setContentText(getText(R.string.nav_service_message))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_no_text_plain_24x24)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setTicker(getText(R.string.nav_service_ticker_text))
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .build();

        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "startForeground");
        startForeground(SERVICE_ID, notification);
    }

    // Now start the GPS updates. Note: Permissions were requested in main activity.
    startGpsUpdates(); // My code to kick off updates.

    return START_STICKY;
```

And that Log.v entry shows up.

I should add my manifest stuff here:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

<service android:name=".NavService" android:foregroundServiceType="location" />
```

But when the phone locks, I get "ActivityManager: Stopping service due to app idle: u0a528 -1m16s853ms com.hubbardsoftware.racetac/.NavService"

Everything works fine up until then. The notification shows up as required. This seems to be per the documentation for long running services.

???
Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Which make/model of device/Android OS version. Also see: https://dontkillmyapp.com/

Comment: try to add android:foregroundServiceType = "location" in your manfiest, and check.

Comment: I do have the foregroundServiceType set.  It is a Samsung 10+ running Android 12.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm experiencing it and it's driving me nuts.